# How to customize the color of Android spinner's dropdown arrow?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner which background is white

[image]

The problem is there's no dropdown arrow, so users wouldn't easily recognize that this field is a spinner/dropdown.

Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
String[] arrPaymentTypes = {"Cash", "Bank Transfer", "Wallet"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spnPaymentTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, arrPaymentTypes);
spnPaymentTypeAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spnPaymentType.setAdapter(spnPaymentTypeAdapter);
```

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:padding="1dip"
/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spnPaymentType"
        style="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/lblPaymentType
        android:popupBackground="@color/white" />
```

**/values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I tried adjusting a few Spinner proprties like `backgroundTint` and doesn't work. What's the proper solution?

Comment: Are you using material designs as library in your dependencies? 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

Comment: @MustafaKhaled Yes: `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'`. Upgrading to v.1.5.0 causes a bunch of cryptic "Android resource linking failed" errors. Some 3rd party libs are used and no idea which one causes the conflict, so I stick at 1.1.0.